# Entity Framework 6 and OCA Clients to Central Server - What to use?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, entity-framework

I've made a WPF/C# application that uses SQLCE 4 with EF5 by using the code first approach.

I now have to make a new application based on this one but it requires a central server and multiple occasionally connected clients. This means that clients need to be offline and sync their data back to the central server (data written in both server and each client).

Besides WPF/C# and the Entity Framework, i'm not decided on any technologies as yet.

From my internet research it appears that the microsoft sync framework is made for this but it seems dated (v2.1 came with SQL Server 2008)? So what options are there to create this type of application with the latest .Net 4.5, WPF and EF6?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: From what I understand Sync got abandoned in favor of Azure. If you are willing to pay for it, you might look into that. I personally tried the Sync framework but ended up rolling my own after a few days. It's possible that you could get it working though.

Comment: Thanks @LordTekkera. You used you're own code to arbitrate what duplicates etc.
I've also heard that people have used Sharepoint 2010 (which i have no idea about). I looked around but all i could see was sharepoint as an office app, rather than the underlying database tech.

Comment: Never used sharepoint, but yes I used my own code to detect updates/duplicates, etc. The sync framework probably works, but its really hard to set up :(